# Quel est le mot français pour le symbole mathématique ∩?

Tags: mathématiques, technologie

Quel est le mot français pour le symbole mathématique **∩** ?

En anglais nous avons les mots "cap" et "intersection"

> **{1, 2}∩{2, 3} = {2}**

[image: a picture of a baseball cap]

Je demanderais sur le [forum Stack Exchange pour les mathématiques](https://math.stackexchange.com/), sauf qu'ils n'autorisent que les questions écrites en anglais.

J'aimerais qu'il n'y ait qu'un seul forum Stack Exchange géré par des balises et je baliserais cette question comme quelque chose comme "mathématiques" et "français". Cependant, pour l'instant, ma question doit aller [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/) ou [là](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Are any of the following acceptable?

- bonnet
- bouchon
- calotte
- capsule
- capuchon
- casquette
- chape
- coiffe
- fond
- joueuse
- plafonner
- toque
- tuque

Comment: "Intersection" me paraît convenir. L'analogie avec les chapeaux ne passe pas. Jamais entendu en classe de maths.

Comment: Since you know the word in English why don't you search for it in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory), and then just change the language to French to get the word in French. This kind of articles on Wikipedia are usually quite reliable. Please read the help centre thoroughly and in particular [this section](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). (*Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs*).

Answer (score 4):

D’après [cet article de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_de_symboles_math%C3%A9matiques) le symbole lui-même s’appelle simplement « intersection » ou « cap », tout comme en anglais, et se prononce « inter » ou « et  » dans son contexte.

Comment: Jamais entendu "cap" dans mes cours de théorie des ensembles du premier et deuxième cycle du supérieur en France. Peut-être à un niveau plus avancé où on hésite moins à utiliser des anglicismes ? Ou on a affaire à une page Wikipedia traduite telle quelle, mais pas adaptée, comme c'est souvent le cas ? Voir aussi https://profgra.org/lycee/BTS-SIO2-U21-11_Theorie_des_ensembles.html#union-et-intersection

Answer (score 3):

Les symboles ∩ et ∪ n'ont pas de nom spécifique en français. On utilise le nom qui correspond à leur sémantique habituelle¹ : ∩ est le symbol ***intersection*** et ∪ est le symbole *union*. Ce sont aussi leur nom officiel dans [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/charts/fr/PDF/U2200.pdf).

Au passage, c'est pareil en anglais. Les noms *cap* et *cup* sont spécifiques à TeX et systèmes dérivés ou inspirés.

À l'oral, ∩ est souvent prononcé « inter » (les deux premières syllabes du mot complet : /ɛ̃.tɛʁ/).

Les rares personnes qui utilisent ces symboles pour autre chose que la théorie des ensembles sont presque toutes des mathématiciens qui écrivent le (La)TeX couramment. Ces personnes sont susceptibles d'utiliser le nom TeX (∩=`\cap`, ∪=`\cup`), quelle que soit la langue qu'ils parlent.

¹  <sub>Comme + appelé *plus*, = appelé *égal*, etc. Très peu de symboles mathématiques ont un nom spécifique, en fait.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Aucun des mots de la liste donnée n'est utilisé. Il existe un vocabulaire alternatif emprunté à la géométrie.

A ∩ B  ≠ ∅ : au lieu de « A inter(section)  B est différent de l'ensemble vide (n'est pas vide) »  on peut dire, au choix :

- « A et B se coupent »
- « A coupe B »
- « A et B se rencontrent »
- « A rencontre B ».

A ∩ B = C : lorsque C n'est pas vide, au lieu de lire cette relation comme d'habitude (A inter(section)  B égale C), on peut dire "A coupe B en C".

Comment: « A et B se coupent », « A coupe B », « A et B se rencontrent », « A rencontre B » ne s'utilisent pas couramment en classes de maths. "A coupe B en C": jamais entendu. Avez-vous des sources? Curieux de voir où vous avez vu cela.

Comment: @Frank C'est une terminologie qui n'est pas très courante et un bon nombre d'ouvrages à ma disposition ne la mentionnent pas ; elle me parait  néanmoins  acceptable; il y a l'équivalent anglais « A meets B » et on pourrait vouloir une traduction qui corresponde (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory).  On la trouve dans le livre « _Algèbre_ » de Michel Queysanne, paru en 1964 aux éditions Armand Colin. Elle a dû être utilisée à l'École Normale Supérieure puisque Queysanne était un normalien.

Comment: @Frank On trouve cette terminologie aussi chez Arnaudiès et Fraysse dans leur _Algèbre_ parue chez Dunod en 1996. Dans ce second cas seulement le terme « rencontre » est mentionné.

Comment: Bourbaki semble utiliser "intersection". Je pense qu'il est plus standard d'en rester à "intersection", "inter" à la rigueur si l'on est pressé.

Comment: @Frank Bien sûr, je ne les recommanderais pas plutôt qu'« intersection ; mais il est utile de les connaitre, et de plus ils font toujours partie de la culture mathématique.

Comment: In English, *union* and *intersection*, or *cup* and *cap* are generally used for actual sets, while *join* and *meet* are generally used for abstract structures inspired by set union and set intersection (*lattices* in English, et *les treillis* en français).

Answer (score 0):

I’m a research mathematician and have never seen *cap* used for the intersection symbol except in LaTeX, etc. And I suspect that the only reason it’s used there is that it’s conveniently short and coincidentally has a rough dual (i.e. lexical counterpart) in *cup*, which LaTeX uses for the union symbol.

Comment: Well, per Steven Schwartzman’s *The Words of Mathematics: An Etymological Dictionary of Mathematical Terms Used in English*, “In the manipulation of sets, the symbol representing intersection … is sometimes called a cap because of its shape.  Contrast *cup* for sound, appearance, and meaning.”

Comment: The intersection symbol ∩ is known as a "cap" in LaTeX because it is toughly the shape of a hat  . Do a google search for "[watch cap](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SLLM_enUS1049US1049&sxsrf=APwXEdednCg6KfzG6oxAhualt32wlqNU9Q:1682475077507&q=watch+cap&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3-tmKvMb-AhVTIn0KHVBnBdUQ0pQJegQICRAB&biw=1845&bih=713&dpr=1.04)".  A synonym of the English word for "hat" is "cap". "cap" is also an American English word for the lid on the top of a plastic soda pop bottle. watch caps and baseball caps, and caps on top of a lid are approximately the same shape as ∩.